# cloud endpoint not respecting Jackson annotations

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, jackson, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a class Organization with few `date` fields as follows.

```
public class Organization {

    private String _id;

    private String name;

    @JsonDeserialize(using=JsonDateDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
    private Date createdTime;

// getters and setters

}
```

To handle the date in simple way on client side I convert `date` to `long` and send it to client using these JsonSerializer as follows

```
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>{

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeNumber(date.getTime());
    }

}
```

I have a endpoint which will execute get organization and insert the results in response map like this.

```
@ApiMethod(name="organization.get", path="organizations/{organizationId}", httpMethod=HttpMethod.GET)
public Map<String, Object> organizationDetails(@Named("organizationId") String organizationId){
    Organization org = DB.getOrganization("123");
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    response.put("status", HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.put("success", true);
    response.put("entity", org);
    return response;
}
```

But the end resultant JSON I see on client side is

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "entity" : [ {
    "_id" : "966a03b3-8e46-41ee-b330-6533409b2b4a",
    "name" : "POKURI",    
    "createdTime" : "2015-05-16T15:02:31.499+05:30"
  } ],
  "success" : true
}
```

Here the date coming in some format instead of long. If I convert the same using Jackson `ObjectMapper` without using cloud endpoints I am getting response in expected way. Why cloud endpoints not respecting Jackson annotations? Is there a way to configure that?

**Note:** Even I observed that `long` is coming as string on client side if you use cloud endpoints. I am using **appengine SDK 1.9.19**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't supposed to use Jackson annotations with Endpoints (and if you do, you have to use the repackaged version, not your own). You can do what you want with `@ApiResourceProperty` or `@ApiTransformer`, depending on how you want to do it. See the annotation documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations).

Regarding `long`, it is serialized as a string due to floating point imprecision--it's not possible to represent all values of a long accurately using a double, which is what JavaScript and `JSON.parse` will store a numeric in, so it is always transmitted as a string. Any of our client libraries for Endpoints automatically convert them to the correct data type.

Comment: Thanks. will start using @ApiTransformer to convert Date to long and vice versa. And I have to handle long on my client side implemented with Angular JS(from which I make REST calls).

Comment: But I see warning on logs If I use repacked package Jackson, my application will stop working application at any moment.